# kubeadm dind won't pull from insecure registry on http

Tags: kubernetes, docker-in-docker

I'm trying to use [kubeadm dind](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubeadm-dind-cluster), but I'm having trouble with private registries.  I created a docker private registry, which is running on http, but kubernetes running in dind refuses to use http, and keeps trying to download using https.

The error I'm receiving is this...

> Failed to pull image "192.168.2.5:5000/inotes-init-db:1.0.18": rpc
>   error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get
>   https://192.168.2.5:5000/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS
>   client

But the registry is running on http...

```
$ curl -X GET http://192.168.2.5:5000/v2/_catalog 2> /dev/null| jq
{
  "repositories": [
    "inotes-init-db",
    "intelli-notes"
  ]
}
```

As you can see above, it works fine on http, but if I try https, it fails...

```
$ curl -X GET https://192.168.2.5:5000/v2/_catalog 
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received
```

I also thought I could maybe access the kubernetes nodes to update their `/etc/default/docker.json` file, but I can't shell into them.

So, how do I get kubeadm to use http?

Comment: you got that error while running `kubeadm` or create a deployment? Not sure `kubeadm` doesn't have that option..... you can also setup https proxy for your http registry...I'm just saying.

Comment: There was a similar [issue](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1131) reported on GitHub, that might be useful for your case.